# How to Properly Set Up UILocalNotification

Tags: ios, xcode

I am developing an app where I need to alert the user using UILocalNotification for a specific time interval

The problem is that I place the code in applicationDidEnterBackground..

So evrytime the user close the app. a New notification is created, resulting in multiple notifications created. How do I go about this problem? Thank you

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{     


}
```

Comment: just cancel them when you enter the foreground again

Comment: Is that how people do it?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Your question can be interpreted

Comment: I would like to prevent multiple notification scheduled on the same time. Your suggestion was to cancel previous created notifications. and I was asking if that is the "normal" approach to this problem? Thank you!!

Comment: How do you want to generate or start local notification, e.g. on button click?